# Can Design Sync be configured to skip retired files during populate to increase efficiency?

Tags: populate, dssc

When populating files in design sync on a vault it fetches the latest of everything everytime one populates.
But it also spends time on retired files everytime. Is there a way to skip working on retired files to save time on populate ? If something is unretired the populate should bring that back anyway.

I dont see any arguments to support this function I am wanting